# How do make iOS autosave received iMessage photos?

Tags: ios, photos, messages

I want to make sure all photos I receive in iMessage are saved to Photos app.

How do I change this settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible. You can bulk save images from a conversation in Messages by opening the conversation details, holding down on an attachment, selecting More, then choosing the photos you want to save and pressing the Save button.